# Why is data not inserted in this code into my database? I suspect a SQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, html

### UPDATED QUESTION

*Previous Question: Why is data not inserted in this code into my database?*

---

*Current* Error recieved:
`INSERT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'all'`

Here is the PHP/HTML code,

```
<?php
/*
    Assignment Form
    by Rohan Verma,
    alias RHNVRM.
*/
// Initialisation
        include('config.php');    
// End Initialisation
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<title>Assignment</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<label>Roll No:</label>
<select name="roll">
<optgroup label="Choose your Roll Number">
<?php
    // Generator for options
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    echo "<option value = '$i'>$i</option>";
}
    //End
?>
</optgroup>
</select>
<label>Your Name: </label> <input type="text" name="u_name"/>
<br />
<label>Name of Person: </label> <input type="text" name="p_name"/>
<br />
<label>About Him:</label>
<br />
<textarea style="width:350px;" name="p_text"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the submission code.

```
<?php
/* 
    Submission 
    by RHNVRM
    +For Project for Assignment
*/

$roll_no = $_POST['roll'];
$u_name  = $_POST['u_name'];
$p_name  = $_POST['p_name'];
$p_text  = $_POST['p_text'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `sv_assign`.`all` (`roll`, `name`, `person`, `about`)
     VALUES (".(int)$roll_no .", " . 
               mysql_real_escape_string($u_name) . ", " . 
               mysql_real_escape_string($p_name) . ", ".
               mysql_real_escape_string($p_text) . ");";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close() or die
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '*********';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'sv_assign';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you insert? Nothing? An error?

Comment: add `or die(mysql_error())` to your mysql_query statement and tell what error it is showing. And one more thing, did you connect to the db

Comment: yea nothing, i know that usually php puts out errors but not this time

Comment: Does your variables that receive data from POST contain data or not?

Comment: Did you establish a connection to the database before doing this query?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'19\', \'Rohan\', \'verma\', \'Did a lot of work.\')' at line 2`    That is the error, i copied half of it from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: why do you have 2 `mysql_connect`?

Comment: I would guess you are getting the error because root doesn't have insert permissions.

Comment: @Rohan Verma, dude, seriously, you have a bad habit of updating your question every time you get a hint from answers provided to your first question and still get problems. Don't do that, you're making the answers irrelevant as you update your `original` question every now and then.

Comment: Hey, I understand your problem @tradyblix but I really need to get it right. I `+1 ed (google sorry for using ur copyright` the respectable answers from my old question. I even +1d u :P

Answer (score 5):

This `\'$roll_no\'` should be just `'$roll_no'`. Same for the rest. 
What's happening is it's becoming the sample below. You're using double quotes to wrap your query string so no need to escape the single quotes inside.

`VALUES (\'value\', \'value\', \'value\', \'value\');`

****EDIT****

Sanitize your code to avoid SQL injections by using `mysql_real_escape_string` or use PDO for handling queries better. Refer to @Daok for the `mysql_real_escape_string` reminder.

**Note**:
This is an answer prior to the OP updating the question with an error in the query.

Comment: well half of this is the solution, cuz i still getting error, `INSERT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'main'`

Comment: not sure if it's gonna be performance issue if you enclose an int with quotes when inserting e.g. `'10', 'string'` vs. `10, 'string`. But it should work.

Comment: @Rohan Verma, give proper permissions to your user, give it INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, etc. privileges.

Comment: but is'nt my account root? how it want more permissinos?

Comment: @Rohan Verma, it looks root to me, yes. but check the privileges to be sure. it's kinda hard to answer your question as I don't see what or how your DB is configured. if the error is access denied, you're missing something, or configured incorrectly. it's not a code issue anymore.

Comment: on the home page o phpMyAdmin it shows `The additional features for working with linked tables have been deactivated. To find out why click here.` Is this the problem? I checked that root has all privileges. It's not my first time with such applications so i think it is the code. lemme update the code on my question maybe.

Comment: @Rohan Verma, it's just phpMyAdmin giving you notices about it's features but I don't see it related to your code. First, fix your SQL. Also were is the part that you include config.php in the script with your query?

Comment: @Rohan Verma, no, after `<?php` you're getting `$_POST` values already.

Comment: Thanks or your support, i am asking another question regarding my error in SQL. Thankx <upvote>

Comment: actually i felt that this answer did not solve my problem since it was already solved i had not escaped it using my method. but the actual problem is probably in SQL

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `sv_assign`.`main` (`roll`, `name`, `person`, `about`)
 VALUES (\'$roll_no\', \'$u_name\', \'$p_name\', \'$p_text\');";
```

Should be changed to :

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `sv_assign`.`main` (`roll`, `name`, `person`, `about`)
     VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($roll_no) .", " . 
               mysql_real_escape_string($u_name) . ", " . 
               mysql_real_escape_string($p_name) . ", " .
               mysql_real_escape_string($p_text) . ");";
```

The mysql_real_escape_string is a good habit to not have SQL injection.

Comment: I used your code, well it reduced the error to half.`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1`. I am guessing that '1' is the roll

Comment: Oops I had put + instead of .

Comment: @Daok, +1 for the effort. The original problem has been answered (query error from original question) but since he's getting some more problems he felt that the answers aren't the one he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove mysql_real_escape_string for the variable $roll_no. Just make sure It's an int when inserting it. You can just do (int)$roll_no. If It's a string, it will be converted to 0, so no worries.

Comment: Disregard, I just noticed Daok's follow up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are 2 issues here:

1. `INSERT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'all'` - this means that the DB user you are connecting from does not have permissions to run INSERT. [Read here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) or contact your server administrator. In fact, this error is weird because you are connection using "root" user.
2. In your INSERT query, you have not enclosed the string values in quotes.

   $sql = "INSERT INTO `sv_assign`.`all` (`roll`, `name`, `person`, `about`) VALUES 
    (" . (int)$roll_no . ", '" . mysql_real_escape_string($u_name) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($p_name) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($p_text) . "'");

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Some times when we use form tag in HTML code , then we should use method post in form tag .I experienced this problem .